# How we can make subquery in linq using two different database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new in Linq.I am facing one situation where i have to make subquery in LINQ using  two diffrent database tables of same server.

Here is my sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.tbl_inv_emoheader where bln_export = 1 and 
str_destbranch in (SELECT systemcode from DB2.dbo.system_contact where    isnull(rovctrlvan_email,'')!='')
```

It works fine for me.

**Problem :**

I want the above query in Linq.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? `mySubQuery.Contains(row.str_destbranch)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this i got the answer

```
  List<tbl_inv_emoheader> CheckMsgid = (from EMOheader in InvData.tbl_inv_emoheaders
                                                  where (EMOheader.bln_export == true && (from i in GetEmail() select i).Contains(EMOheader.str_destbranch))
                                                  select EMOheader).ToList();


private static IEnumerable<string> GetEmail()
    {
        List<string> strEmails;
        using (SharedSynchDataContext dc = new SharedSynchDataContext(Connections.Getencompass3()))
        {
            strEmails= (from l in dc.system_contacts
                    where (l.rovctrlvan_email != string.Empty)
                    select l.systemcode).ToList();
        }
        return strEmails;
    }
```